# Get String value from JSON document

Tags: javascript, json

```js
valeurs_d = "";
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length -1 ; i++)
valeurs_d += + event[keys[i]] + ", ";
var str5 = ",";
var str6 = str5.concat(valeurs_d);
var valeurs = str6.substring (0, str6.length - 2);
console.log(valeurs);
```

I have a json document like this :

```js
 {
  "temperature" : 12.45,
  "lala" : 45.75,
  "humidite" : 45.78,
  "toto" : "gvvgvh",
  "topic" : "sk1_001/data"
 }
```

The problem when I retrieve the values. I have the following result: 12.45, 45.75, 45.78, NaN!

I want to retrieve my string instead of NaN, How ?

edit : Thank you, it's donne, but I hava annoter question :

Typeof in Javascript returns number or string, or I want to return varchar for string, and double for number.

I need this to write on my Apache Cassandra database in node.js.

How can I proceed to return varchar and double ?

Comment: `+ event[keys[i]]` remove the `+` - You are casting your string into a number

Comment: What Weedoze is referring to is known as a [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Unary_operators), specifically the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), which attempts to convert its operand into a number. For example, `+"3"` returns `3`, `+true` returns `1`, or in your case, `+"gvvgvh"` returns `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you, 

Typeof in Javascript returns number or string, or I want to return varchar for string, and double for number.

I need this to write on my Apache Cassandra database in node.js.

How can I proceed to return varchar and double ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you just want a list of all the values in your object. This should do the trick :

```js
let obj = {
  "temperature" : 12.45,
  "lala" : 45.75,
  "humidite" : 45.78,
  "toto" : "gvvgvh",
  "topic" : "sk1_001/data"
 }

let values = Object.keys(obj).map( key => obj[key] )

console.log(values)
```

So you get all values in an array, but if you want a string, you can always do `values.join(",")`.

Comment: thank you, Typeof in Javascript returns number or string, or I want to return varchar for string, and double for number.

I need this to write on my Apache Cassandra database in node.js.

How can I proceed to return varchar and double ?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think it's possible, as `varchar` and `double` are not Javascript types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all values in a string with comma delimited, try code as following

```
var obj = {
 "temperature" : 12.45,
 "lala" : 45.75,
 "humidite" : 45.78,
 "toto" : "gvvgvh",
 "topic" : "sk1_001/data"
 };


var a = []; 
for(var k in obj){
  a.push(obj[k].toString());
}
var result = a.join(",");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, 
Typeof in Javascript returns number or string, or I want to return varchar for string, and double for number.

I need this to write on my Apache Cassandra database in node.js.

How can I proceed to return varchar and double ?